# Continuous function from $(0,1) \to \mathbb{R}$ with minimun and maximum.

Tags: calculus

> Construct a continuous function from $(0,1) \to \mathbb{R}$ with minimun and maximum.

I was convinced that $f(x) = \sin^2(\pi x)$ would have met these conditions, but it seems that this one doesnt have a minimum? Some cubic would also probably work here?

Comment: Why $\sin^2(\pi x)$ should not have a minimum?

Comment: There must be some other conditions on your function, otherwise the question is uninteresting: should it be surjective, injective, increasing ... ? Do you need a local maximum, or a global one ?
Otherwise, the constant function equal to 0 is continuous, has a minimum and a maximum (at each point), and takes real values.

Comment: @joshua: it just means the image of $(0,1)$ under the mapping $f$ is a subset of the real numbers, not that it should be surjective.

Comment: @gabrielek: the function approaches $0$ at the endpoints but never equals $0$. Can you see why this means this particular function doesn’t have a minimum?

Comment: Ah, my bad. I did not considered the fact that nor $0$ nor $1$ are considered as part of the domain.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Try to construct a piecewise function by joining lines together at specific points. In this way, you can create a non-constant function with a maximum and a minimum.